# How to set global custom property in MyBatis with Spring configuration

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

It like to be able to set custom properties in MyBatis java config that I can reference later in my XML mappers.  I've created a config class that sets two beans:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        
        dataSource.setDriverClassName( driverClassName );
        dataSource.setUrl( url );
        dataSource.setUsername( userName );
        dataSource.setPassword( password );
        
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        
        Properties configurationProperties = new Properties();
        configurationProperties.put("userStatus", UserStatusCodeEnum.DELETED.getValue() );
        
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setConfigurationProperties(configurationProperties);     
        
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
```

In the second bean, set a custom configuration property with a key named "userStatus".  I'd like to be able to reference that in my mapper, such as: `${userStatus}`, but that does not seem to work.

I've found examples of setting this up using XML config, but I prefer to use the Spring boot java methods.

Comment: I tested it using the spring-boot template in this [repo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and it worked as you expected. So, if it does not work in your project, there may be something else wrong with the setup. You should try the template yourself and make small changes one by one to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  I appreciate it.  In my case, I suspect that MyBatis is not using my SqlSessionFactory bean.  How do I inject that bean into the MyBatis context?

Comment: It's not easy to resolve a problem in already messed-up Spring project. If you share the project source, someone might be able to find the cause/solution. Or, you can find it yourself by using the method I proposed.